# despite that I used "margin: 0 auto", section is 10px more on the right side

Tags: html, css

The `section` on [my page](http://skeptar1.lima-city.de/index.php?content=create_tutorial), should be in the middle of the page. Here the code if the `section`:

```
section{
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 100px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
width: 1000px;
```

but the section is 10px more on the right side. If you change the size of the page you can see it better:

[image]

I hope you can see my problem and can help me. Tell me if you want that I write the whole css file here.

Comment: The extra 8px is not from the `section` element. The `border: 4px solid rgb(25, 25, 25);` to the `article` is adding the extra 8px.

Comment: did you set any other paddings etc. for the div containing *section*? probably would be helpful to see some more css code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your article tag is overflowing the container. Its width ends up being 300px + 4px + 4px because of the border. If you set the `box-sizing` to be `border-box`, width will account for border correctly:

```
article {
  width: 1000px;
  border: 4px solid rgb(25, 25, 25);
  background-color: rgb(75, 75, 75);
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

A lot of frameworks, such as Twitter Bootstrap, will do `*{box-sizing:border-box;}` because it's much more intuitive.

Edit:

Note that while this solution is a common pattern, changing `box-sizing` in an existing page can create other things to pop up, especially since you've been using `px` widths instead of percentage based widths. You may want to just do a `width:308px` to the `section` prevent the other issues.

I would recommend `border-box` as more robust, but it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You explained it really good. I made a embarrassing mistake..., but thanks!